# How can I differentiate between Branches and Feature Branches

Tags: java, git

In my project I am creating a repository, branches, and feature branches in GitLab using the Java API.

```
Repository      --- Repository in Git 
Branch          -- From the Master
Feature Branch  - From Branch
```

We have more than 100 branches and feature branches in the same repository.

Now, I am trying to get all the branches for a given repository, but instead I get both branches and feature branches.

Is there a way I can get a list of branches along with a list of their specific feature branches?

Comment: Why did you tag this with `java`? It doesn't seem relevant

Comment: I tag java Because I am Using Java API to performing all the task from my Application instead of login in git and perform from there.

Comment: By Using naming convention we can resolve that issue but I am looking something except this.

Ex-For Branch we can use Branch-BranchName
    Same way for Feature Branch -Feature-BranchName

Comment: A "feature branch" is still a `branch`. Git doesn't make this differentiation. Naming convention is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a namespace like feature/foo to separate the feature branches from other branches. Then you could list all feature branches this way:

```
$ git branch --list feature/*
```

Comment: Thanks Tino
I am aware of  namespace but If I am working with some existing repository where namespace is not used then it will be difficult .
And I am looking Feature Branch and its corresponding Branch.